# Jquery append ajax load after div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

im trying to insert a ajax loaded content after a div tag

```
$('#optionheader').after($.load('calendar', {'requestType':'loadMenu'}));
```

can anybody tell me where the error is?

thx

Comment: Where does the browser tell you the error is?

Comment: the menu that should be loaded doesent appear     ... if i use $('#menucontainer').load('calendar', {'requestType':'loadMenu'}); to append it to an extra created div it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
     var div = $("<div />");
     div.load('calendar', {'requestType':'loadMenu'});
     $("#optionheader").after(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.get for this:

```
$.get('/calendar', {'requestType':'loadMenu'},function(data) {
    $("#optionheader").after(data);
});
```

If you want to do it your way, with .load, you could do it like this

```
$("#optionheader").after($('<div />').load('/calendar',{'requestType':'loadMenu'});
```

This should add a div to the #optionheader tag and load it with the result of /calendar

Comment: whats the difference between $.get and $.load?

Comment: $.load is intended to load the data into an the jquery selector it is called from.  $.get is just for making a generic GET request (ie. to load a web page).  They are both really just wrappers around the base $.ajax function